# How do I access data in a view in Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In standard WebForms, I would have a handful of properties, and set those. Then the Web Page would bind to them, for example with `<%#CustomerName%>`.

I understand that MVC is a different approach, but there must still be a basic need for displaying data from multiple sources at the same time.

I can see that if I use `@Model` then it will access the data set in the controller. But what if You want to display data from 2 or 3 separate items?

If I want to display a `Customer`, their address and their current order all on the same page, is there a way of passing these 3 seperate models to the one view, or is it a case that I need to create a partial view for each, and then display them all on the same page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a `ViewModel` which holds all those data(classes) as properties and return that to your view

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public Address Address{ set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { set;get;}

  public CustomerViewModel()
  {
    if(Address==null)
        Address=new Addres();
    if(Orders ==null)
        Orders =new List<Order>();

  }
}
public class Address
{  
   public string AddressLine1 { set;get;}
   //Other properties
}
public class Order
{  
   public int ORderID { set;get;}
   //Other properties
}
```

your GET Action method

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  var vm=new CustomerViewModel();

  vm.Name=repo.GetUser(id).Name;

  vm.Address=repo.GetAddressFromUserID(id);

  vm.Orders=repo.GetOrdersFromUser(id); 

  return View(vm);
}
```

And your View will be strongly typed tp `CustomerViewModel`

```
@model CustomerViewModel

<p>@Model.Name</p>
<p>@Model.Address.AddressLine1</>
@foreach(var item in Model.Orders)
{
  <p>@item.OrderID</p>
}
```

Comment: You and George both have the same solution and same votes, but you were first I think, thanks.

Comment: @Matt it doesn't matter, but if you hover over the timestamp (as of this writing, the `yesterday`: I was 42 seconds faster than Shyju).

Answer (score 4):

Are the items related? If they are, then consider creating a ViewModel that is an aggregate of each model:

```
public CustomerViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer {get; set;
    public AddressViewModel Address {get; set;}
    public OrderViewModel Order {get; set;}
}
```

then in your view:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<CustomerViewModel>

@model CustomerViewModel

@Model.Customer.Name

@Model.Address.Street

@Model.Order.Name

@model.Order.Date
```

Otherwise, if the items are *not* related at all, then you can use the `RenderAction`:

In your `Customer` view:

```
@Model.Customer.Name

@(Html.RenderAction("GetAddress", "Customer", new { customerId = Model.Customer.Id });) 

@(Html.RenderAction("GetOrders", "Order", new { customerId = Model.Customer.Id });)
```

Comment: So I assume that GetAddress and GetOrders are methods are properties in the controller?

Comment: @Matt they should be actions in the controller if you're calling `RenderAction` (that is, if they're really separate things -- the orders should be, but I'm not so sure about the address. I'd rather make the Address part of the ViewModel and render the orders separately through a `RenderAction`.

Comment: @Matt And the orders could very well (and probably should be) in their own controller anyway (since they're a separate resource).

Comment: In which case, if I follow the pattern you are suggesting, am I linking 2 controllers to the one view, or are you suggesting one view nested inside the other / as a partial?

Comment: @Matt The RenderAction allows you to call different Controllers from one view without that view having to know what's getting inserted into it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll stop asking questions now as Im deviating from the original. Thanks again, and Im sure I'll be asking more things soon :(

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is create a collection on your `Model` to contain the three customer models.  When we are talking about Models in MVC, it is helpful to think of them as `ViewModels`.  That is to say one model per view which will contain all of the data for that view.

So in the example below you have collection of customers from your data model set as a property on your view model.  You can now iterate over `@Model.Customers` in your view (or in an Html helper extension method)

**Example**

```
public class MyViewModel{
    private List<Customer> _customers;

    public List<Customer> Customers{
        get{
            return _customers;
        }
    }
    //Other View Model Properties and Methods
}
```