# MVC 4 Html.ActionLink is not passing parameters to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I am somewhat new to MVC and trying to rewrite login page to MVC. 
I can not pass parameters to my ActionResult in controller, the parameter coming in is null.

here is View

```
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
</div>
 </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
@Html.ActionLink("GO!", "AppList", "LogIn", new { @userName = Model.UserName}, null)
</button>
```

I am trying to pass user name and password into my controller.

```
  public ActionResult AppList(string userName)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I looked  up other post and i sure i am using proper overload for this.

Here I added route config

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LogIn",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "LogIn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

this is my actionResult that is loading login page

```
public ActionResult LogIn(string userName, string password)
        {
            ViewBag.LogInButton = "Log In";

            return View(new Login());
        }
```

and view i assign a model

```
@model LogInPortal.Controllers.LogInController.Login
```

Comment: Is `Model.UserName` a NON NULL value ?

Comment: @Shyju if you mean my model? Yes, its not a null-able field
 public class  Login
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Did you alter the default route definition ?

Comment: No. I mean the value coming to Model.UserName property

Comment: @Shyju - yes, values coming in as null, I edited post to show config

Comment: So that is the problem. You need to fix that :)

Comment: @Shyju - I cant understand why its coming in as nulls though? any idea?

Comment: Are you setting that value in your GET action method ?

Comment: @Shyju - no, i am trying to pass values from my @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName) and then filter database on that. but my parameters coming in as null on my action result.
also, i checked fiddler and i do see query string with parameters.

Comment: `UserName` is a property of your viewmodel to which your view is strongly typed to. Are you not passing an object of your view model from your action method to the view ? If yes, are you setting the UserName property value ?

Comment: i updates my post to show you what exactly i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the link will issue a GET request, but will not submit the form data. You need a submit button inside your form to submit the form field values

```
@model LogInPortal.Controllers.LogInController.Login
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login","AppList"))
{
  <div class="row">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password)
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And mark your action method with HttpPost attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(string userName, string password)
{
  // do something with the posted data and return something
}
```

Or you can even use the same Login class object as your parameter. The default model binder will map the posted form data to the property values of that object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(Login model)
{
  // do something with model.UserName and model.Password
  // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: I tried above still getting null parameters in my controller
after i manage to pass parameters i will update this to post, trying to get bones here :)

Comment: Are you sure your GET action request is having userName and password in querystring ?

Comment: Now Just checked fiddler, no query string coming in :/

Comment: I guess you need to fix that. I think you need to understand how to pass data from your action method to view. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635811/how-do-i-access-data-in-a-view-in-razor/11635908#11635908)

Comment: thank you for the link, 
in my case im trying to pass data from textbox to my actionResult. it works fine if i am passing date from ActionResult to view :)

Comment: Next time when you write the question, you need to clearly include all those information :) Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: sorry i confused you 
you are life saver. now  i understand why it wast working for me :), silly silly me